# reading a record header from csv file - java

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file which looks like this :

```
Field 1    field 2                             field 3             
TestData   MARTIN,12/2/2/2:JOHN 12/2/2      2015/12/12
```

I want to extract from `field 2`, the names e.g. `Martin` and `John`. I read in the file and split by `,` . That does not fully work because `field 2` contains commas inside and it splits it. Is there a work around for this or a way to extract the data from a particular cell (e.g. just give me all field 2 from the file)?

Comment: That doesn't look like a CSV file to start with. And in CSV syntax it's common to escape commas with wrapping contents in double quotes (eg: `"John", "1,231.23", "Male"`)

Comment: If unescaped commas exist in fields, this is not a CSV file, but rather a TSV (tab-separated values) format.

Answer (score 0):

In general if the fields on a CSV contain comas, they need to be quoted. So a line should look like this:

`TestData,"MARTIN,12/2/2/2:JOHN 12/2/2",2015/12/12` to be a proper CSV.

Are you sure you don't have a TSV (tab-separated-values) file? In that case, you can split do

```
String[] fields = line.split('\t')
String[] persons = split(1).split(',')
```

Comment: Although, on closer inspection "MARTIN,12/2/2/2:JOHN 12/2/2" doesn't seem too regular either. You seem to have a ',' after Martin and a ' ' after John. SO you may have to write something more custom using `String.indexOf` and `String.substring`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle CSV files is to use a CSV library.  I use OpenCSV http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/  but there are others. OpenCSV handles escaping commas quite well, along with reading headers, etc. It also handles tab delimited files.

Answer (score 0):

Fields containing commas should be quoted in the CSV, and fields containing quotes will have them escaped by another quote. For example:

```
"here's a comma, and some ""quoted text"" as well"
```

However, the CSV "format" is a bit of a nightmare, [with no proper specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard).

I wouldn't recommend trying to write your own parser when [good ones already exist](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).